# Set field value based on saved search

Tags: netsuite

I want to set total sold quantity in last six months in custom field on item and want to use that for other customization.

I am able to display it on the field using summary search but not able to save it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of a Saved Search custom field is calculated every time the record is displayed and not stored in the database, which is why you can't use it directly in other customizations. A workaround is to have a second field which stores the value, and then you can use a Workflow or script to copy the field value.